# Function with char array parameter

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, parameter-passing

I'm trying to write a function for printing text in C for PIC microcontrollers (I think it's based on gcc).

```
void print(char[] text);

void print(char[] text)
{
    for(ch = 0; ch < sizeof(text); ch ++)
    {
        do_something_with_character(text[ch]);
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
print("some text");
```

I'm getting compiler complaints about wrong brackets.

1. What is wrong with this?
2. How can I use char array pointer in this case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Comment: actually `char[] text` isn't a valid C syntax. It should be `char text[]` or `char *text`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
void print(char *text);

void print(char *text)
   {
   while(*text)
      {
      do_something_with_character(*text);
      ++text;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 9):

The correct syntax is

```
void print(char text[])
```

or

```
void print(char *text)
```

In `print()`, you cannot use `sizeof` operator to find out the length of string `text`, you need to use `strlen()` (include `<string.h>` first) or test whether `text[ch]` is `\0`.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in other answers, your syntax is incorrect. The brackets belong *after* `text`.

Also of significant importance, [`sizeof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) does *not* do what you're expecting here:

```
void print(char[] text)
{
    for(ch = 0; ch < sizeof(text); ch ++)
                     ^^^^^^
```

Remember, `sizeof` is a *compile-time* operator - the compiler replaces it with the size while the code is being built. It can't possibly know the size at runtime.

In this case, `sizeof(text)` is always going to return `sizeof(void*)`, or 4 on most 32-bit systems. Your platform may vary.

---

You have two options:

- Pass the length in another parameter to print.
- Treat the `char[]` as a ["C string"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string), where the length is unknown, but the string is terminated by  NUL character.

The latter is your best bet, and you should probably replace `char[]` with `char*`.

Here we use a NUL-terminated string, and iterate over it with a pointer:

```
void print(const char* text)
{
    const char* p;

    // Iterate over each character of `text`,
    // until we reach the NUL terminator
    for (p = text; *p != '\0'; p++) {

        // Pass each character to some function
        do_something_with_character(*p);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I dynamically measure size of that char array?

Comment: @Kamil See [`strlen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strlen.html). But note: When dealing with typical C strings, you rarely care what the actual length of the string is.

Answer (score 2):

You have to place the square brackets in the correct place:

```
void print(char[] text);

void print(char[] text)
```

```
void print(char text[]);

void print(char text[])
```

or use pointer notation:

```
void print(char *text);

void print(char *text)
```

Also, note that even if you use the array notation, the parameter is effectively rewritten to a pointer, and then the code in the body of the function:

```
for(ch = 0; ch < sizeof(text); ch ++)
```

is wrong.  You almost certainly don't want the 4 or 8 bytes that is the size of the pointer.  You probably want:

```
size_t len = strlen(text);
for (size_t ch = 0; ch < len; ch++)
```

If you can't declare variables in your loop (C99 or later required), declare it separately.  You didn't show the declaration of `ch` in your code.  If it compiled, that means `ch` is a global variable — which is pretty horrid.

Note that the `++` operator binds tightly and should not be separated from its operand by spaces.

Comment: What's the point in leaving a descriptive explanation? Just give meh teh sampl codez plz.

Comment: 'Tis the way of the world.  There's no point in getting upset about it, even though from most points of view, it would be justifiable.

Answer (score 1):

Pass C-style string by pointers, or brackets after variable name:

```
void print(char *text);
                ^
```

or

```
void print(char text[]);
                    ^^
```

To calculate the length of a string, use `strlen` not `sizeof`.

```
int len = strlen(text);
for(ch = 0; ch < len; ch ++)
                 ^^^^
```

Comment: Note that using `strlen()` in the loop condition converts a linear algorithm into a quadratic algorithm as the length is evaluated on each iteration unless the compiler is really smart and can determine that nothing changes the length of the string.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Good point, edited. I'm coming from C++ realm which calling `string::length()` in the loop is not bad.

Answer (score 1):

Judging on your question and the observation that you are probably a beginner in C, I'll attempt to answer your question without using pointers like the other answers here.

First off, Jonathon Reinhart makes an excellent point, that `sizeof` is not the proper usage here. Also, as others pointed out, the correct syntax for an *array of characters*, which is what you are using in your code, is as follows:

```
// empty character array
// cannot be changed or given a value
char text[];

// character array initialized to the length of its content
char text[] = "This is a string";

// character array with length 1000
// the elements may be individually manipulated using indices
char text[1000];
```

In your case, I would do something like this:

```
#include <string.h>

void print(char text[]);

int main()
{
    char text[] = "This is a string";
    print(text);

    return 0
}

void print(char text[])
{
    // ALWAYS define a type for your variables
    int ch, len = strlen(text);

    for(ch = 0; ch < len; ch++) {
        do_something_with_character(text[ch]);
    }
}
```

The standard library header `string.h` provides the `strlen` function which returns an integer value (actually an unsigned long) of the length of the string **excluding** the terminating NULL character `\0`. In C, strings are just arrays of characters and the way you specify the end of a string is by including `\0` at the end.